# How to use JQuery to change the same type of CSS

Tags: jquery

How to change the same type CSS??

eg.

```
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #1e5799 0%,#7db9e8 100%);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #1e5799 0%, #7db9e8 100%);
```

Will .eq(0) work on this case??

```
$('.block').css("background.eq(0)", '-webkit-linear-gradient(left, #1e5799 50%,#7db9e8 100%)' );
$('.block').css("background.eq(1)", '-moz-linear-gradient(left, #1e5799 50%, #7db9e8 100%)' );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will not work. Try this based on browser check.

```
if($.browser.webkit){
  $('.block').css("background", '-webkit-linear-gradient(left, #1e5799 50%,#7db9e8 100%)' );
}

if($.browser.mozilla){
  $('.block').css("background", '-moz-linear-gradient(left, #1e5799 50%, #7db9e8 100%)' );
}
```

Comment: I have another question. if -webkit-gradient & -webkit-linear-gradient,they are webkit.What should I do?

Comment: -webkit-gradient is for /* Chrome,Safari4+ */ & -webkit-linear-gradient is for /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */. They are webkit too.How can check this?

Comment: You can use `$.browser.version` to check for specific version of the browser.